# Cómo mostrar resultados de comandos de servidor linux en PHP

Tags: php, linux

¿Cómo puedo mostrar los resultados de un comando de un servidor **Linux**? Es decir, si yo escribo `htop`, que me muestre los resultados en una página de php esos resultados.

Intenté hacerlo de esta forma y no me funcionó.

```
$salida = shell_exec("htop");
 echo "<pre>$salida</pre>";
```

Pero digamos si quiero mostrar los resultados de este comando sí me los muestra

```
$salida = shell_exec("df -h");
echo "<pre>$salida</pre>";
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer eso?

Llevo varios días tratando de sacar eso y no he encontrado la forma.

Answer (score 1):

Htop es un programa interactivo que se ejecuta en un bucle hasta salir, el comando df -h tiene una salida de texto no es interactivo por eso si lo muestra php en este caso si quieres mostrar esos parámetros podrías ejecutar top -n 1 y con javascript hacer peticiones ajax para hacerlo un poco mas dinámico.

Agrego la pagina de [htop](https://hisham.hm/htop/).

También puedes ver [utilizar htop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15538687/using-php-to-stream-data-of-programs-such-as-htop).

Answer (score 1):

No todos los programas se pueden ejecutar desde PHP. Si queres ejecutar htop, lamento informarte que no se puede. 
Cuando un programa es interactivo, no se puede hacerlo desde PHP.
Pero si tu intensión es ver algunos procesos podes usar algunos que le reemplazarían:

```
<?php
    // Si queres CPU.
    echo "Mostrar CPU: ";
    $cpu = preg_split('/[\s]+/', shell_exec('mpstat 1 1'));
    $cpu = 100-$cpu[42];
    echo "<pre>$cpu</pre>";

    echo "Mostrar ps: ";
    $output = shell_exec('ps -Ao %cpu,%mem,user,comm');
    echo "<pre>$output</pre>";

    // Si queres top, pero no tan amigable..
    echo "Mostrar top: ";
    passthru('/usr/bin/top -b -n 1');
```